# Add graticules to a SpatRaster in terra

Tags: r, terra

I want to map sample locations on a map of Antarctica.

```
library(terra)
r<-rast("IBCSO.tif")
#IBCSO.tif was downloaded from https://ibcso.org/current_version/
v<-vect(lonlat, crs="+proj=longlat")
p<-project(v, crs(r))
plot(r)
points(p, col="red", pch=20, cex=1)`
```

gives me the [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFSc2.png).

```
> rast()
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 180, 360, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84
```

```
> crs(r)
[1] "PROJCRS[\"WGS 84 / IBCSO Polar Stereographic\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n        DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4326]],\n    CONVERSION[\"IBCSO Polar Stereographic\",\n        METHOD[\"Polar Stereographic (variant B)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9829]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of standard parallel\",-65,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8832]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8833]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",north,\n            MERIDIAN[90,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            MERIDIAN[0,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Hydrography and nautical charting.\"],\n        AREA[\"Southern hemisphere - south of 50°S onshore and offshore, including Antarctica.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,-50,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",9354]]"
```

I would like to add a layer of graticules with steps of 5 degrees latitude and 10 degrees longitude on top of this map. How can I do that?

Comment: can you create (with `rast()` a SpatRaster like `r` and include that in your question? That would make your question reproducible and would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @RobertHijmans: `r` is basically a dbm covering Antarctica in EPSG: 9354. I'd say he wants to add a lat/lon grid to the polar stereographic data. Issue should not be dependent on the data type used and is reproducible using `r <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(country = "Antarctica", type = "countries") |> terra::vect() |> terra::project("EPSG:9354"); p <- terra::spatSample(r, 30)` in my opinion.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and the example? The comments are not a good place for that.

Comment: @RobertHijmans: I already tried several times but I'm only getting notifications à la "edit queue is full". No idea if I am missing something, still pretty new here, or if it is expected to try for half a day?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize it was not the OP who commented. They should make the edit. Perhaps your reputation is too low?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what information is missing? I have added >rast (); and crs ()

Comment: @aaltenburger: Not exactly missing, but your example is not very convenient since one needs to download a raster of ~150 MB. This is unnecessary from my point of view, since you seem to be interested in having a lat/lon grid overlay to your polarstereograpgic projection, so actual data is not needed and the issue can be reproduced using `r <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(country = "Antarctica", type = "countries") |> terra::vect() |> terra::project("EPSG:9354"); p <- terra::spatSample(r, 30)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take extending the approach provided by [falk-env](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11709296/falk-env).

You can use `sf::st_graticules()` to get more controlled graticules. So with that you can control the steps of the longitude and latitude lines independently:

```r
library(terra)
library(dplyr)

# I downsample here the tif for full reproducibilty and speed increase
# url: https://download.pangaea.de/dataset/937574/files/IBCSO_v2_ice-surface_RGB.tif
# 161.9 Mb
# r <- rast("IBCSO_v2_ice-surface_RGB.tif")
# r2 <- spatSample(r, size = 500000, method ="regular", as.raster = TRUE )
# writeRaster(r2, "IBCSO_downsample.tif")


r <- rast("IBCSO_downsample.tif")


# Substitution for `lonlat`
v <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(country = "Antarctica", type = "countries") |> 
  vect() |> 
  project("EPSG:9354") 

p <- spatSample(v, 30)

# Create graticule object with sf
grat <- sf::st_graticule(lon=seq(-180,180, 10),
                      lat = seq(-90,0, 5),
                      ndiscr = 5000) %>%
  vect() %>%
  project("EPSG:9354") 


# Base plot

plotRGB(r, axes=TRUE, mar=5)
plot(p, col = "red", add = T)
plot(grat, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

If you want the labels to be in longitude/latitude degrees, you may try with `ggplot2` + `tidyterra`. Basically, overlap the `grat` object and use the `scale_x/y_continuous()` trick for labelling only:

```r
# Human readable with ggplot2

lims <- as.vector(ext(r))

library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data=r) + 
  geom_spatvector(data=p, color="red") +
  geom_spatvector(data=grat, color=alpha("grey60", 0.5)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = lims[c("xmin", "xmax")],
           ylim = lims[c("ymin", "ymax")]) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-180, 180, by = 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-90, 90, by = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing at `sf::st_graticule()`!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100 % sure if I really got your question, but let me give shot, at least to provide a starting point for others knowing better:

`terra::plot()` has a `grid = TRUE` attribute but this option only seems to allow you to draw grid lines of the coordinate reference system of the raster to be displayed. This won't help you here, since you do not want a grid of EPGS: 9354, but EPSG: 4326 ("in steps of 5 degrees latitude and 10 degrees longitude").

Maybe there is an option to override this default which I'm not aware of. So I'm going to apply a little trick here and simply sketch graticules as an additional vector object consisting of lines, e.g. the [graticules dataset](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-graticules/) from NE.

```r
library(terra)
library(dplyr)

# This vector dataset shoud be sufficient for demonstration purposes
r <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(country = "Antarctica", type = "countries") |> 
  vect() |> 
  project("EPSG:9354") 

# Substitution for `lonlat`
p <- spatSample(r, 30)

# Read, split, filter correspondig to your requirements (= only every second meridian), 
# and merge again; Maybe not the most elegant approach.
graticules <- sf::read_sf("ne_10m_graticules_5.shp") 

lat <- graticules |> filter((direction != "E" & direction != "W") | is.na(direction))
lon <- graticules |> filter(direction == "E" | direction == "W") |> filter(degrees %% 10 == 0)

gr_new <- bind_rows(lat, lon) |> vect() |> project("EPSG:9354")

# Inspect result
plot(r)
plot(p, col = "red", add = TRUE)
plot(gr_new, add = TRUE)
text(gr_new, gr_new$display)
```

[image]

As a result, we can tick off the coordinate system part, but not the "human readable" requirement, since all labels are placed on the same spot - and again, I'm not sure if it is possible to enforce a better label placement when working with `terra::text()`.

Alternatively, you can make use of `{tidyterra}` to be able to use `{ggplot2}` with `SpatRaster` and `SpatVector` objects from `{terra}`. A minor tweak of `scale_x_continuous` seems to produce the graticules you're looking for but then again, labeling along the frame is far from perfect here.

```r
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatvector(data = r) +
  geom_spatvector(data = p, col = "red") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-180, 180, by = 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I have tried to rephrase my original question.