# Show grid lines above `geom_spatraster` but below data points in `ggplot2`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra, tidyterra

I am drawing a raster map with points on it in `ggplot2` using `tidyterra`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)

backmap <- ne_download(scale=50, type="MSR_50M", category="raster") # will download a 17MB map
data <- data.frame(longitude=runif(10, -180, 180), latitude=runif(10, -90, 90)) # simulate points

ggplot(data, aes(longitude, latitude)) +
  geom_spatraster(data=backmap) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_sf(crs='+proj=lonlat', expand=F)
```

[image: Plot1]

**I would like to have the graticules drawn above the raster map**, for now they are below it and only visible if the map is not fully opaque:

```
ggplot(data, aes(longitude, latitude)) +
  geom_spatraster(data=backmap, alpha=.5) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_sf(crs='+proj=lonlat', expand=F)
```

[image: Plot2_alpha]

I know I can have the grid above everything using `theme(panel.background=element_blank(), panel.ontop=T)` like described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48865035/14993291), but then the points are below the grid which I don't like.

I am aware of a workaround with `sf::st_graticule()` suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958745/14993291) but wonder if the redundancy of drawing the same grid twice can be resolved by the `ggplot2` magicians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sf` package is your friend here. Note the point in the example image just above Papua New Guinea, it's in front of the graticules. Also, it is better practice to convert all your spatial vector data, such as your points, to `sf` objects with defined crs. I have omitted the raster import steps but kept your object names the same:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyterra)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Sample point data
set.seed(1)
data <- tibble(longitude=runif(10, -180, 180),
               latitude=runif(10, -90, 90))

# Generate graticules
graticules <- st_graticule(lon = seq(-180,180, 60),
                           lat = seq(-90,90, 30)) %>%
  vect()

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = backmap) + 
  geom_sf(data = graticules, color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = data,
          aes(x = longitude, y = latitude),
          color = "black") +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-180, 180, by = 60)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-90, 90, by = 30)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly what I wanted because I would still have to think of the grid line spacing etc. myself. Also similar to the answer of @teunbrand but more applicable for my case. Maybe still the easiest option out there, so accept this answer for now.

Comment: @taprs - Thanks for the rep. Yeah, couldn't think of an easier way. My favourite metaphor for R is that it's like an ATV: it can go almost anywhere, but you have to drive it yourself. And what often seems to be a convoluted path is often (but not always) the easiest. The beauty of R however is that once the code is written that  achieves a goal, you can recycle that code again and again. One thing that would *slightly* improve the workflow would be create variables for the graticule spacing/axis breaks. That way you'd only have to edit them once.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble installing (tidy)terra, so I don't know if this will work for your data object, but generally, you can add a manual graticule in between your raster and points.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

world1 <- sf::st_as_sf(map('world', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

ggplot(world1) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = sf::st_graticule(world1), colour = "red")
  # geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>